# OAuth0 in react & nodejs environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, single-page-application, access-token

I have a site with React frontend (SPA) and NodeJS backend (for APIs) with NGINX.
I want to implement OAuth0 authentication for this site.

How can I use the authentication flow for the frontend & the backend APIs?

Like this:

- Login in frontend (*/login*), the user gets an **accessToken** from OAuth0,
- When needed data from backend, call the backend API with this **accessToken**
- The backend checks this in OAuth0, from where the frontend received this **accessToken**.

The site:

https://recognitiongame.eu

Thanks,

Imre

Comment: You wrote a normal way of auth - it will work. But what is `Oauth0`? 
if you need just authorization you can use jwt signed token instead of an access token, and impement ready recept, for example: https://www.bezkoder.com/react-jwt-auth/
Or if you want to use facebook Oauth try https://github.com/simov/grant for backend

Comment: Thanks for your help. The React examples helped to understand.

Oauth0: I want to implement with the help of: https://auth0.com/

Answer (score 0):

My [SPA and API code example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1) provides some code and blog posts on getting started with this type of solution - and the configuration of both SPA and API can be repointed to Auth0. React has very little to do with it and it is more about design patterns.

SPA security can be a difficult journey though, due to browser restrictions and security concerns, and the solution you choose may depend on the sensitivity of your data. For a more state-of-the-art option, see [this Curity code example](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff).